# How to set limit of number of entries while requesting a json from subreddit

Tags: python, python-3.x, reddit

```
async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as cs:
    async with cs.get('https://www.reddit.com/r/memes/hot.json') as r:
        res = await r.json()
```

This is my code to get json from reddit but it only gets 25 entries. How to get more than that?

Comment: Pass the `limit` value along with the url as a get parameter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding `?limit=somevalue` should give you more results.

```
https://www.reddit.com/r/memes/hot.json?limit=100
```

Comment: This solves it but is there a way to get more than 100 results?